# TreeNode.Remove doesn't work !

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have a strange problem. Let's look at that code:

```
TreeNode tn = TreeView1.FindNode("2009/08/12 (1)");     //OK, the Node is found
```

Now, I need to delete that node:

**(IT DOESN'T WORK !)**

(e.g. (I know that I don't need to use TreeView1.FindNode() method, but **i = -1**))

```
            TreeNode tn1 = TreeView1.FindNode(tn.ValuePath);
            int i = TreeView1.Nodes.IndexOf(tn1);
```

or

```
            TreeView1.Nodes.Remove(tn);
```

The problem is, the codes above doesn't work, I mean, the node isn't removed, why ?
The TreeView looks like that:

[alt text http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/230/71970321.png](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/230/71970321.png)

Comment: Do us a favor add a couple of Console.WriteLine() and post up what your output is.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that the TreeView control in .net only allows to remove First Level Nodes, so if the node you are trying to delete is not this kind of node, you need to delete it trough its parent, using something like this:

```
Dim Padre As TreeNode = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Parent
If (Padre Is Nothing) Then
    TreeView1.Nodes.Remove(TreeView1.SelectedNode)
Else
    Padre.ChildNodes.Remove(TreeView1.SelectedNode)
End If
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you've selected the node properly?  If `TreeView1.Nodes.IndexOf(tn1)` is returning **-1**, this indicates the node can't be found.